# OpenGL code to render ribbon diagrams for protein

Tags: c++, open-source, opengl, protein-database

I am looking to render ribbon diagrams of proteins using OpenGL and C++.  Does anyone know if any open source code for this already exists, or if there are good guides to do this?  If not, I'd prefer to figure it out myself ;) but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel, especially if the wheel was free.

EDIT: thanks for the responses.  Does anyone know if any of these programs have good documentation about the reasoning behind why they store certain vertices or triangle meshes for rendering based on the structure of the atoms in the protein?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://molvis.sdsc.edu/visres/molvisfw/titles.jsp for an amazing number of projects devoted to molecular visualization, most of them open source.

Answer (score 1):

For java, there's [ProteinShader](http://proteinshader.sourceforge.net/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to adapt the [Visualization Library](http://www.visualizationlibrary.com/jetcms/) for your use.

The [GLE Tubing and Extrusion Library](http://linas.org/gle/) looks like it should be able to do your ribbons.